# Demonstrate the slam with kinect on turtlebot without other hardware

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , as the title says , how can i demonstrate the slam with kinect on turtlebot without other hardwares? As I can simulate the signal lacked.Is it workable ? Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38793/demonstrate-the-slam-with-kinect-on-turtlebot-without-other-hardware/) by [Yum.my](https://answers.ros.org/users/2780/yum.my/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To build a map and then navigate autonomously in that map, follow the turtlebot_navigation tutorials:

1. building a map: http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM
2. navigating autonomously in a known map: http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2